# Change parent element proportions while keeping child proportions correct

Tags: javascript, css

I have a parent element that is animating its shape from landscape to portrait and vice versa. The parent element contains an image, which as its parent changes shape, is getting distorted. I want the image to maintain correct proportions, staying in the middle of the parent while being cutoff at the edges for example.

This is similar to how an image maintains proportions using `object-fit`, but I can't use that here because the parent is animated using transforms to avoid layout thrashing.

A simplified example of my problem:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

parent.addEventListener('click', () => {
  parent.animate(
    [
      { transform: 'scale(1, 1)' },
      { transform: 'scale(0.5, 1.5)' }
    ],
    { 
      duration: 560,
      fill: 'forwards',
    }
  );
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure class="parent">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/560/320/arch">
  </figure>
</div>
```

What would be a good approach to this problem?

Comment: Can you post a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do/358993#358993) of this problem as your [mcve] so that a solution specific to the code can be created?

Comment: You may want to consider using a `div` as `width:100%; height:100%; background:center / cover no-repeat url(yourURLHere.png);`.